# Service in Domain Driven Design

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm creating an application to try DDD.
The application is for rent movies, my classes are:

```
class Movie{
     String title
     String descrition
}

class Customer{
    String username
}

class Rent{
     Film film
     User user
     Period period
}
```

For what I know of DDD I had also a `RentService` to create a `Rent` object. So I have:

```
class RentService{
     Rent rentMovie(User user, Film film, Date from, Date to){
         //validation check (like if the film is already rented)
         return rentRepository.store(new Rent(user, film, from, to));
     }
}
```

In the end the `RentService` just create a new `Rent` object and then store it using a repository. Is it correct?
Then, I want to offer a button to *RentNow!* in the web application that rent for a period of 3 days from today, do I should add a method `rentNow` in `RentService` which calculate the days or can I re-use the old method and calculate that dates in the Controller class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the end the RentService just create a new Rent object and then
>   store it using a repository. Is it correct?

For the most part yes. Rent service is an [application service](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/14/services-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/). However, who's responsible for providing the `User` and `Film` entities to the service. It can be the controller, however you can also have `RentService` itself do that. The controller would only be responsible for passing IDs:

```
Rent rentMovie(int userId, int filmId, Date from, Date to)
```

The service would have to reference the appropriate repositories. The benefit is that the "rent movie" operation is full encapsulated by the service and the controller has fewer responsibilities.

For RentNow, also create a dedicated method on the application service. This seems like a business use case so it should be made explicit on the service.